# Unit test with testNG in spring boot takes time to build project

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, testng

I have created a web application in spring-boot. I am writing a unit tests with testNG for my business layer.

I have created Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Mapper mapper()
    {
        List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        mappingFiles.add("dozer-mappings.xml");
        return new DozerBeanMapper(mappingFiles);
    }
}
```

My test classes are looks like

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestApplication.class })
public class CommissionRuleServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
     @InjectMocks
     @Autowired
     MyService

     @Mock
     MyDAO;

     @BeforeMethod
     public void initMock()
     {
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }

     @Test(dataProvider = "....")
     ......
     ......
}
```

When I run project it shows hugh log on console and it takes times say 20.00secs for just few small tests.
Some of statements from log are,

> DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory
>   DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor 
>   DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner 
>   DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
>   DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
>   DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.ArrayConverter 
>   DEBUG org.dozer.loader.xml.XMLParser
>   DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder
>   DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.TableBinder
>   DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : MyEntity
>   DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
>   DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL

Why it is taking such a "hugh" time? What should I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

The investigation:

**The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent** to the following annotations with default attributes:

1. `@Configuration` - Indicates that the class contains one or more `@Bean` methods. Plays together with `@ComponentScan`.
2. `@EnableAutoConfiguration` - Will attempt to guess and configure beans that you are likely to need. **This might cause some performance penalty depending on your application.**
3. `@ComponentScan` - Configures component scanning. As the package is not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class with this annotation.

Without more code it is not possible to give you an accurate guess, but I think **most of the performance penalty is caused by Spring Boot initialization**.

Answer (score 0):

By default the logging level is set to INFO in Spring Boot, probably you changed that?
Add this to application.properties or any other level you need (TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF)

logging.level.root=WARN

As was said before auto configuration may impact performance.
You can play with excluding some configurations that you don't need.
Here is an example (random set - don't follow blindly)

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, SessionAutoConfiguration.class,
        ValidationAutoConfiguration.class, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class, WebSocketAutoConfiguration.class,
        DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class, EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class,
        JmxAutoConfiguration.class, MultipartAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        JacksonAutoConfiguration.class, SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class,
        MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class, SendGridAutoConfiguration.class, FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class,
        GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.class, DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration.class,
        SitePreferenceAutoConfiguration.class, MustacheAutoConfiguration.class,
        PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class})
```

for test classes I would recommend using

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
```

also you can exclude Tomcat if you don't need it in your tests

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and try to give us more details